# Is there a possibility for numpy to replace a for-loop for performance improvements?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, optimization, dataset

Is there a way to improve the performance of this code with numpy or python in general?
The goal is to build a trainings set. `features` is the raw data. I want to use a moving window approach with a striding lenght of 1 to ''enrich''' the data. In the end I want ro reshape the data from a 2D array to a 3D array, because one training input has the shape `(windowSize, features.shape[1])`.

```
import numpy as np

windowSize = 4
features = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12],[13,14],[15,16],[17,18],[19,20]])
featuresReshaped = features[:windowSize]

for i in range(1, features.shape[0], 1):
    featuresReshaped = np.vstack((featuresReshaped, features[i:i+windowSize]))

maxindex = int(featuresReshaped.shape[0]/windowSize) * windowSize
featuresReshaped = featuresReshaped[:maxindex]
featuresReshaped = featuresReshaped.reshape(int(featuresReshaped.shape[0]/windowSize), windowSize, featuresReshaped.shape[1])
```

Comment: I tried  ```print(featuresReshaped)``` at the bottom, and the bottom slice (```featuresReshaped[-1]```) breaks the moving window pattern a little, is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Using repseated `vstack` is slow.  Collect the windows in a list, and do just one `vstack` at the end.  It's possible to make a moving-window `view` with `as_strided` (or windowing functions that use it), though subsequent operations might force a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for your reply. I don't understand it fully. Can you show me a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution avoids all the looping and whatnot by using NumPy indexing.

```
import numpy as np

windowSize = 4
features = np.array(
    [[ 1,  2], 
     [ 3,  4],
     [ 5,  6],
     [ 7,  8],
     [ 9, 10],
     [11, 12],
     [13, 14],
     [15, 16],
     [17, 18],
     [19, 20]]
)

indices = np.add.outer(np.arange(len(features) - windowSize + 1), np.arange(windowSize))
# indices:
# [[0 1 2 3]
#  [1 2 3 4]
#  [2 3 4 5]
#  [3 4 5 6]
#  [4 5 6 7]
#  [5 6 7 8]
#  [6 7 8 9]]
features[indices] # indices must be of type np.ndarray or this won't work
# features[indices]:
# [[[ 1  2]
#   [ 3  4]
#   [ 5  6]
#   [ 7  8]]

#  [[ 3  4]
#   [ 5  6]
#   [ 7  8]
#   [ 9 10]]

#  [[ 5  6]
#   [ 7  8]
#   [ 9 10]
#   [11 12]]

#  [[ 7  8]
#   [ 9 10]
#   [11 12]
#   [13 14]]

#  [[ 9 10]
#   [11 12]
#   [13 14]
#   [15 16]]

#  [[11 12]
#   [13 14]
#   [15 16]
#   [17 18]]

#  [[13 14]
#   [15 16]
#   [17 18]
#   [19 20]]]
```

It should be noted that your code outputs something different from mine, which I believe may be an error, as your last slice is:

```
print(featuresReshaped[-1])
# [[15 16]
#  [17 18]
#  [19 20]
#  [17 18]]]
```

which is inconsistent from the "moving window" description you have provided.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This way it is about 4756 times faster. :) I know. My implementation cuts the last part away. Where did you learn to use numpy correctly? Can you point me in one direction? :)

Comment: @Pm740 Good to know it helped! I have mostly learned through experience (I do a lot of numerical computing for personal projects and studies). I am kinda obsessive with "cool numpy tricks", so everytime I see someone do something interesting (that I don't understand) with numpy I always try fully to understand the code. Most of the tricks I use are  often some combination of numpy indexing and broadcasting, which is quite well documented here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html. Good luck with learning numpy!